# Random pair generation?

Tags: combinatorics, random

Suppose there are 6000 people, there will be a combination of $$\binom{6000}{2}$$ ways for 2 people to be chosen out.

Now the task is to randomly choose 5000 pairs of people in the total 6000 people.

One possible solution is to:

1. list all possible pairs $$\binom{6000}{2} = 17997000$$
2. randomly choose 5000 pairs.

There is one problem with this solution, it is very task heavy to generate 17997000 pairs first.

Is there any method to generate 5000 random pairs directly, without firstly generate all possible pairs then do random choose?

Comment: Define "Random"

Comment: Choose a random integer between 1 and 6000. Then choose another random integer between 1 and 5999.

Comment: @Ethan [Random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness), though I don't see how this helps answer the question.

Comment: One way to do it (assuming uniform distribution), is to take a random permutation (again, uniform distribution) and pick first $2n$ to generate $n$ pairs. Observe that you don't need to explicitly specify how the unused rest of the permutation looks like, for example you could use [this shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and stop at the appropriate place. This would be similar to picking one person after another uniformly from the available pool, like AnonSubmitter85 suggested.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 The question of Ethan is about the distribution, without it "random" does not mean anything. I assume that the OP wanted uniform over all pairs (fortunately it coincides with other uniform distributions).

Comment: @dtldarek One can talk about algorithms that involve random numbers w/out specifying what distribution they come from, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 In algorithms randomness is just another input and in majority of cases it is assumed to be uniform and independent for each bit (and this is enough for specifying distribution). In other cases randomness extractors are used, or some other tools which later make the analysis possible. Without distribution this would be moot, i.e. [all the bits could be zero](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: coming up with a number of pairs doesn't necessarily require coming up with all possible pairs. OP seems to have disappeared.